# How to call a function on a variable without type?

Tags: java, variables

I need to set "Themes" for my Java desktop app. For that i need to run different Java Classes depending on user input. For that I declared a variable of type object:

```java
public Object theme;
```

and I later set the variable type in a function:

```java
//get theme
        String theme_selector = prefs.get("theme", "default");

        //choose correct one
        switch(theme_selector){
            case "modern 2d":   theme = new Modern("2d"); break;
            case "modern 3d":   theme = new Modern("3d"); break;
            case "circles" : theme = new Circles(); break;
            default: 
                theme = new Default();
                break;
```

This function gets called before everything else.
Later on in the program, in another function, I need to call theme.draw(). Every class that theme could be has a draw function, but I still get an error, as the IDE still sees "theme" as a variable of type Object.
How do I get around this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't use `Object` but a proper interface that declares the method `draw()` and that all themes need to implement, e.g. something like `interface Theme { void draw(); }` and `class Modern implements Theme { ... }` - and of course `public Theme theme;` :)

Comment: Btw, I'd probably also get rid of the switch-statement but use a `Map<String, Theme>` where the key is the theme name. Then I'd do something like `Theme theme = themes.computIfAbsent(theme_selector, Default::new);` That way you can add new themes without having to change the switch statement and for every unsupported theme selector you'd get one instance of `Default` (you could also use one single instance and then just do `themes.getOrDefault(theme_selector, defaultThemeInstance)`).

Comment: As @Thomas already said, do not use `Object`. Reason is simple: Every class implicitly inherits `Object`. So, let's say you are using a function to draw and you pass an object of type `Object`. You now have to test if there is a function `draw()` and only then call it, otherwise an Exception will be thrown. Using interfaces, you can avoid that test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an interface that gets implemented by `Modern`, `Circles` and `Default` with all the methods, then you have

```
public ThemeInterface theme;
```

instead of `public Object theme;` and it'll work.

e.g.

```
public interface ThemeInterface {
    public void draw();
}
```

and

```
public class Modern implements ThemeInterface {
    // implement draw here 
    public void draw() {
         // magic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Modern`, `Circles` and `Default` should all implement an interface that declares a `draw()` method (e.g. `Drawable`). theme should be kept as a `Drawable` and not as an `Object`.

Example:

```
interface Drawable {
  public void draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not declare `theme` as an `Object`. You have more information than that.

Instead, create either an abstract class, or (probably better suited) an interface called `Theme`, and ensure that all your theme types (e.g. `Modern`, `Circles` etc) either implement or extend `Themes`.